# Post data to an API using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-core

I am new to Angular and would like to know how to post data.

I have a controller made in Angular :

```
myApp.factory('employeeServices', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var factoryDefinitions = {
     moveToBench: function (employeeId) {
            var data = $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    "entityId": employeeId,
                    "nextStateId": myApp.state.bench
                })
            });
return $http.post(myApp.IndecommBaseUrl + '/Workflow',data).success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    }

    return factoryDefinitions;
  }
]);

//Controller
myApp.controller('getEmployeesController', ['$scope', 'employeeServices', 'dataTable',  function ($scope, employeeServices, dataTable) {
    employeeServices.getEmployees().then(function (result) {
    $scope.moveToBench = function (id) {

            employeeServices.moveToBench(id);
        }

    });
}]);
```

I have a button in HTML :

```
<button class="btn  btn-success" ng-click="moveToBench(employee.employee.id)">Move To Bench</button>
```

On button press, I can see that the values in :

```
 moveToBench: function (employeeId) {
            var data = $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    "entityId": employeeId,
                    "nextStateId": myApp.state.bench
                })
```

are correct. But while it reaches the API, its value is NULL..

The backend API controller is :

```
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(int entityId, int nextStateId)
        {
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Config.Json"));
            string jsonFile = jsonObject.GetValue("WorkfowJsonFileLocation").ToString();
            var nextState = _stateServices.Get(nextStateId);
            var handler = new WorkflowHandler(nextState, jsonFile, _entityServices, 1, _stateServices, _subStateServices, _appServices);
            handler.PerformAction(entityId);
        }
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the return statement is called before the params are set. Please try the inline version:

```
moveToBench: function (employeeId) {
     return $http.post(myApp.IndecommBaseUrl + '/Workflow', $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                        "entityId": employeeId,
                        "nextStateId": myApp.state.bench
                      })
                }))
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
```

Comment: its giving me some syntax errors... lemme try fix that

Comment: yeah sorry, parantheses were not balanced. i edited my answer.

Comment: I made the changes. But still im getting NULL value. Also a new error popped up : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" and "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51703' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: CORS is enabled. so it might not how it looks like''

Comment: Hm I'm not an asp expert but are you sure that you want your parameters sent as json string when the server expects two parameters?

Comment: How do you enable CORS ? it looks like it's not enable, else you don't receive this error. And I think you must add the `FromBody` attribute on your parameters, your method signature should looks like `public void Post([FromBody] Model model)` where `Model` is a class with your 2 fields.

Comment: Im sure that CORS is enabled in the back end. And I am not sure if sending parameters as json string is causing the issue. Do you have any other suggestions?